# How Many Generation We can Run a Mycelium of Pleurotus ostreatus/Pearl Oyster?

Tags: mycology, cloning, mushroom

I am able to grow mycelium successfully on the spent coffee grounds. And mycelium is successfully fruiting once/twice on the same substrate. I am cloning by taking mycelium from the existing one (which is fruiting at present) and transfer to the new jar and run it for 8-10 days and use it in new box for fruiting next generation.

What I am growing is 4th generation(I mean the transfer cycle).

As I am Newbie, I have done some sort of research and started with a master spawns (got it from govt. mushroom labs). But I am not able to understand one thing is.
Is it ok to clone using mycelium or do I need to do spore cloning or need to go for master spawn spawns now and then or its ok to continue to nth generation and keep eating the fruits.

Is there any serious issues with my cloning?